# Help with relation between $G$-modules and representations.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, modules, representation-theory

The following is from the book *Algebra* by P.M. Cohn.
Let $V$ be a $G$-module of dimension $d$ with basis $\{ v_1,...,v_d\}$. Then there is a corresponding representation $\rho : G\rightarrow\text{GL}_d$ by defining the action of $x\in G$ on $v\in V$ by

$$
v_ix=\sum_j\rho_{ij}(x)v_j
$$
The author says that the representation defined in this way is "afforded" by the $G$-module. If we take another basis $u=(u_1,...,u_d)$, then we again get a representation $\sigma$ by defining
$$
u_ix=\sum_j\rho_{ij}(x)u_j
$$
Let $P$ be the matrix of transformation from $u$ to $v$ so that
$$
v=Pu,\qquad u=P^{-1}v.
$$
and therefore
$$
\sigma(x) u=u x=\left(P^{-1} v\right) x=P^{-1}(v x)=P^{-1} \rho(x) v=P^{-1} \rho(x) P u .
$$
which shows that $\sigma(x)=P^{-1}\rho(x)P$, and hence $\sigma$ and $\rho$ are equivalent representations.

The above is easy to understand. But the author then writes "Moreover, since $P$ may be any invertible matrix, we see that representations of $G$ that are equivalent are afforded by the same $G$-module for suitable bases" - this part I do not understand. How exactly do we see from the above that the $G$-module $V$ affords all representations that are equivalent to $\rho$?

Comment: Use `$\{ x\}$` for $\{ x\}$.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: All representations on the same vector space $V$ equivalent to $\rho$ are related to $\rho$ by an equivalence (intertwiner, equivariant isomorphism, whatever you want to call it), which is an invertible transformation $P$. Then the equivalent transformations are just conjugates of $\rho$ by various $P$s. 
@Shaun You think this question lacks context?

Comment: Well . . . Yes, because there is none, @runway44.